# Does Ubuntu installer preserve btrfs @home subvolume while installing / to the @ subvolume on the same parttion?

Tags: partitioning, btrfs

On my laptop (Dell Lattitude E7470) I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on a btrfs partition (`/dev/sda2`)
using the standard `@` and `@home` subvolumes for `/` and `/home` mountpoints.
There is also an EFI system partition (`/dev/sda1`).
These are the only partitions in the system (I have no other OS installed).
These are my partitions in `/dev/sda` as seen by `gparted`.

[image: 1]

I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 over the current 16.04, but would like to keep my `/home` intact.
(That is how I used to upgrade,
but I used to keep `/home` on a separate ext4 partition, not a btrfs subvolume.)

Will the Ubuntu installer respect and keep my `@home` subvolume?
When I select manual partitioning and specify `/dev/sda2` as a btrfs partition,
it is not clear that the installer is aware of the subvolumes.

Answer (score 4):

Well, since I got no answers, I risked proceeding with the installation anyway.
I'm reporting what I did, and the result, so it may help others and myself in the future.

### What I did

1. Before starting, make an external backup of the important stuff in `/home`, of course.
2. Boot the live Ubuntu 20.04 from a USB flash drive,
   and chose "Try Ubuntu without installing".
3. Mount `/dev/sda2` btrfs partition on `/mnt/`
4. Delete everything inside the `/mnt/@/` root subvolume.
   (I previously made a btrfs snapshot of the subvolume,
   just in case something went wrong and I would have to restore the old system back.
   Fortunately this was not needed, but I'll keep the snapshot around for a while
   so I can compare configuration files in `/etc`, for instance.)
5. Unmount `mnt`.
6. Start the Ubuntu installer.
7. On the "Installation type" window ([see it on the tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-allocate-drive-space)),
   choose "Something else".
8. On the partitioning window (a screenshot would be nice here),
   choose `/dev/sda2` partition, specify mount point = `/` and no formatting.
   (There is no option for mount point `/, /home`, which would be clearer.)
9. On the "Who are you" window ([see it on the tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#9-login-details)),
   enter a username equal to my previous main (`uid=1000`) username.
   (This should be optional, but this way the main user will immediately "inherit" the previous homedir from `/home`.)

The installation proceeded fine from then on.

### Result

Upon reboot, the system started fine, both `/` and `/home` were mounted from the `@` and `@home` subvolumes, as expected, and I logged in to my account with no issues.

### Summary

Apparently the Ubuntu installer will keep the `@` and `@home` subvolumes if it finds them on the brtfs filesystem, and will mount them as `/` and `/home`

If you want to overwrite the `/` volume, as I did, you should clear it first.
I tried once without clearing, and the installation eventually failed.

Comment: I played a bit with this since I have a SSD about to fail:

At step 4 I recursively deleted @ using `rm -R`. Then it wouldn't let me unmount /mnt. I tried to force unmount it but was unsuccessful.

Then during the install there was no / to install 22.04 to. But I clicked on the "empty" partition and named it "/". Then ran the installer as you described. After it completed my old home folder was still there.

BTW recursively deleting @ deleted an experimental btrfs subvolume that I had created, but left /home.

Comment: A deeper dive revealed that the experimental btrfs subvolume is still there. But its associated folder is gone.